# Misconfigured apach2.X and php 5.6.8

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have a problem with a misconfigured apache2 server and the php 5.6.8 verson. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I installed apache2 and php 5.5.9 from the default repo. But I want to use php 5.6.8 because the integrated phpdbg, so I downloaded it from the php's website and installed it. Now I have 2 different version. According the `phpinfo()` the php version is 5.5.9 and I ran the `php -v` in the shell and it said the version is 5.6.8. I tried to remove the old php, but it did'nt help me.

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You need to tell apache which php version to use.

Comment: Okey. And how can I tell it? I installed php 5.6.8 in my home directory.

Comment: Answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use

Comment: I know nothing about Ubuntu but it should be loading mod_php somewhere inside /etc/httpd/. (Did it really still use PHP/5.5.9 after you uninstalled it?)

Comment: I can't remember the solution, but I could fix it. I think the problem was I load old PHP and I had to rewrite the path to the new version of PHP.